# Cannot make vsftpd work, logging in as anonymous

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I want to configure my vsftpd server to accept anonymous FTP.

I used the following `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES

local_enable=NO

write_enable=YES
anon_root=/tmp/
anon_max_rate=2048000
xferlog_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=NO
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

And then I restarted vsftpd with:

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

And then I tried to connect to the FTP server from another PC as "anonymous",
but I got an error:

```
$ ftp 192.168.1.68
Connected to 192.168.1.68.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (192.168.1.68:mohamed): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Login failed.
ftp>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's a "new" security feature
`vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot`

You must disable write rights on the root dir 
`chmod a-w yourdirectory`

This was reason enough for me to move to **pure-ftpd**

Comment: what's the root dir in my case?

Comment: you have set `anon_root=/tmp` but i wouldn't recommend disabling write rights on tmp, that would affect many other things, better make another directory